# how to convert spark web api endpoint to spring boot endpoint properway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spark-java

I have created a api endpoint using spark for education purpose. Now i need to convert this implementation to the springboot and need to consume the request parameter within the implementation.Following codes show how i have implemented both application...But how can i consume request from spring boot application. Following implementation wont give the request body.

```
package com.spark2springboot.application;

import static spark.Spark.*;

public class spark2SpringbootTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        post("/api/spark2springboot/receive", (request, response) -> {
            String str = new String(request.bodyAsBytes());
            return str;
        });
    }
}
```

Spring boot implementation

```
@RestController
public class EmailMessageController {

    @PostMapping(path = "/api/spark2springboot/receive", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public void spark2springboot(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,) {
      String str = CharStreams.toString(request.getReader());
      return str;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply refer to 'https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body'. For more information, see the official documentation.